# Javascript - Why below function definition errors out?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

```
var a = [3,5,2,6,8];
var i = 0;
function x(a[i]) { //This line errors out, why?

}
```

Please explain why above line errors out? and I am trying to print array elements in reverse order using recursion. If you can write the code also, would be fantastic!

Comment: The argument declaration, `a[i]`, is invalid syntax. Just `a` will do.

Answer (score 1):

you pass value to function definition. you have to give it when you call function, not when defining 
function. you can pass a value when you call a function.

```
var a = [3,5,2,6,8];
var i = 0;
function x(t) { 

}
x(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function with an argument incorrectly. You give a name to your function arguments, just like any other variable:

```
function x(array) {
  //Do something with your array
}
```

And then you call the function:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
x(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
var a = [3,5,2,6,8];
function x(p, len) {
   if(len >= 0){
     alert(p[len-1]);        
     x(p, len-1);
   }    
}
// and call
x(a, 5);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhqr0qm5/4/)

Comment: No reverse functions to be used...logic only invited!

Comment: @sahilsharma added recursion to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on other answers, you are sort of mixing function declaration and function evaluation (call).

This declares the function `x` that accepts an `a` parameter:

```
function x(a) {

}
```

And this calls a function `x` with argument `a`:

```
var a = [3,5,2,6,8];
x(a);
```

or directly:

```
x([3,5,2,6,8]);
```

Regarding to the recursive function to reverse an array, this could be an option:

```
var a = [3,5,2,6,8];
function x(a) {
    if (a.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
    return a.slice(-1).concat(x(a.slice(0, -1)));
}
```